# Problems clearing text input on event using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XyWfr/5/). Problem is when it disables the inputs it doesn't clear the input in the text field.

Here is the jquery...

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
$('.begin-date-picker').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            $('input.needs-begin-date:checkbox').each(function(iControls){
                this.disabled = false;
            })
            $('input.needs-begin-date:text').each(function(iControls){
                this.disabled = false;
            })
        }
        else{
            alert('empty');
            $('input.needs-begin-date:checkbox').each(function(iControls){
                this.checked = false;
                this.disabled = true;

            })
            $('input.needs-begin-date:text').each(function(iControls){ 
                this.disabled = true;
                this.val('');
            })
        }
});
```

This can be recreated by...

1. Input date
2. Check the check box enter text in the text box
3. Remove the date

Comment: Have you tried changing `this.val('');` to `$(this).val('');`?

Comment: Or `this.value = "";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either wrap `this` in a jQuery wrapper:

```
$(this).val('');
```

Or even better pull the `value` held within `this`:

```
this.value = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be `$(this)` instead of `this`.

Updated and working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XyWfr/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(this).val(null);
```

use this in

```
 $('input.needs-begin-date:text').each(function(iControls){ 
                this.disabled = true;
                this.val('');
            })
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XyWfr/7/